# Visual Studio 2012 IntelliSense

Tags: visual-studio-2012, intellisense

I have a small problem with VS2012, I've never used it before so...
Here is my problem I have a variable named age.
But when I start typing if(age and then press space , VS automatically write "AggregateException" and so on for many other words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typing a word in the wrong context will generate unexpected behaviors.

Make sure that you are typing in the right place.

```
public class Test
{
    public void Met()
    {
        int age;
    }

    public void Met2()
    {
        age /* invalid scope for age */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in enabling **Intellisense Suggestion Mode**, see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/01/22/intellisense-suggestion-mode-vstipedit0012.aspx) for further information.

You can enable it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> while in the text editor. Once you enable it, Intellisense will only auto-complete when you press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key or when you double-click on an item in the list.

This allows you to type full-stops, space characters and other special characters without Intellisense getting in the way (handy for test-driven development)!